# How can I forced shutdown thread in my parent class

Tags: java, android

I have a activity inheritance form parent calss.Now,I need to close parent's thread when I leave my clild activity.I don't know how to do that.

This is my base class.

```
public abstract class SerialPortActivity extends Activity {
 public class ReadThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while(!isInterrupted()) {
            int size;
            try {
                if (mInputStream == null) return;
                size = mInputStream.read(buffer);
                if (size > 0) {
                    onDataReceived(buffer, size);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mApplication = (Application) getApplication();
    try {
        mSerialPort = mApplication.getSerialPort();
        mOutputStream = mSerialPort.getOutputStream();
        mInputStream = mSerialPort.getInputStream();
        /* Create a receiving thread */
        mReadThread = new ReadThread();
        mReadThread.start();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        DisplayError(R.string.error_security);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        DisplayError(R.string.error_unknown);
    } catch (InvalidParameterException e) {
        DisplayError(R.string.error_configuration);
    }
}
protected abstract void onDataReceived(final byte[] buffer, final int size);

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mReadThread != null)
        mReadThread.interrupt();
    mApplication.closeSerialPort();
    mSerialPort = null;
    super.onDestroy();
 }
}
```

And this is my sub class.

```
public class ConsoleActivity extends SerialPortActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.console);
}
@Override
protected void onDataReceived(final byte[] buffer, final int size) {
    totalSize += size;

    if(totalSize>=8996){
        analysis();
    }else{
        for(int temp = 0 ; temp < size ; temp++){
            totalbyteArray[countTotalByte] = buffer[temp];
            countTotalByte++;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to close mReadThread when I leave ConsoleActivity.And when I restart ConsoleActivity,the mReadThread will restart together.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `SerialPortActivity` class add refrence for `ReadThread` like this:

```
public ReadThread mReadThread;
```

Then in subclass you can access to `mReadThread` and for handle lifecycle you must override the `onStart` and `onStop` methods. like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mReadThread != null) {
        mReadThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mReadThread != null) {
        mReadThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

**MORE**: It's good to write a method for initializing `mReadThread` in the parent class and in some case if `mReadThread` object is null at starting the thread you can 
call that method. something like this:

```
public void init() {
   mReadThread = new ReadThread();
   mReadThread.start()
}
```

then in `onStart` you can write:

```
    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mReadThread != null) {
        mReadThread.start();
    } else {
        init();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I leave Console activity,I clear all activity with   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);  But when I restart Console activity,There are two mReadThread like 03-12 12:27:41.759 1671-1709/android_serialport_api.sample D/totalSize: 128
03-12 12:27:41.759 1671-1746/android_serialport_api.sample D/totalSize: 128
03-12 12:27:41.759 1671-1709/android_serialport_api.sample D/mReadThread: Thread-140
03-12 12:27:41.759 1671-1746/android_serialport_api.sample D/mReadThread: Thread-147

Comment: @Gary in `onStop` method after the interruption thread, try to set null on mReadThread. I mean `mReadThread = null;`